# Syntax error when adding js file in runtime

Tags: javascript, jquery

So i am trying to add a js file at runtime i have this simple HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>test</title>
    <script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
    <script src="main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body onLoad="init();">
</body>
</hmtl>
```

And in the main function i have this

```
function init() {

    $.getScript("bots/test.js");
}
```

I am getting a syntax error in the first line of test.js which cointains this function

```
function hello(){

    console.log("hello");
}
```

But the thing is if i call the hello function in main.js after making sure the test.js file got loaded it works. So why is there a syntax error?

If i include test.js in the html the error isnt present either.

Note: The error message doesnt prevent anything from what i can tell everything still works.

EDIT: Error message under chrome:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///G:/tt/Desktop/black%20box/bots/test.js?_=1424695256510. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.
```

To answer some questions i use a click event on a button to call the "hello()" function, which works fine (outputs hello in console and doesnt trow any error).

Comment: Provide error message in question itself.

Comment: the error message is just "syntax error" at line 1 nothing else, this is in firefox

Comment: Which browser? Try using chrome, usually error message is more clear

Comment: one reason for syntax error might be the function you are referring `hello` has not loaded so browser reports error. but when it gets loaded it just works fine.

Comment: @JenishRabadiya — That would give a *reference* error, not a syntax error, and only if that function was called, which it isn't.

Comment: Share the test.js file please

Comment: @Quentin hmm... I learnt that. that means problem must be in test.js file.

Comment: @A-NirVaan — Isn't that what the last code block is?

Comment: How are you calling `hello()`? Because `getScript` is an asynchronous function.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. [It runs without errors](http://test-cases.dorward.me.uk/stackoverflow/28673907/).

Comment: Wait, that's not a syntax error... Maybe this issue is just relevant on chrome which doesn't allow access to `FILE` protocol, run it on local server

Comment: edited question with more data

Comment: That error message (a) isn't a syntax error and (b) tells you exactly what the problem is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///G:/tt/Desktop/black%20box/bots/test.js?_=1424695256510. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

`getScript` loads files via Ajax. You can't do Ajax on local files. Do your testing on a webserver.

Comment: I plan on using this localy, so i just need to drop getScript, and load the file without using ajax?

Comment: That would be an alternative approach, yes.

Comment: Yep used native methods to load the js file, works now without errors. But why did it work before also if ajax didnt work?

Answer (score -2):

`$.getScript` uses ajax to asynchronously retrieve the file, then execute it, it is defining a hello function but not calling it. You could call the function in the `$.getScript` success handler:

```
$.getScript('bots/test.js', function () {
    hello();
});
```

Comment: Issue is the syntax error caused by cross-origin request policy, not the function not being called.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you should add a `<html>` tag before your `<head>` ?

Comment: The start tag for the HTML element is optional.